# SQL Server TRIGGER IF Value Exist then Change it to Something else

Tags: sql-server, database, if-statement, triggers

I have a table called `dbo.PBXDATA`. I want to set a trigger where if the value of column SALES_REP equals a specific value(int), then change that value to the name of the sales_rep in the Table column. Below is what I have so far. Any hints would be great. Thank you.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.PBXDATA_trgIUD_sales_rep
   ON  dbo.PBXDATA
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT CAST(WHEN SALES_REP = '101'
THEN 'Ryan Kosterow'
ELSE 'NULL'
END as NVARCHAR) FROM dbo.PBXDATA

SELECT CAST(WHEN SALES_REP = '115'
THEN 'Robert Messing'
ELSE 'NULL'
END as NVARCHAR) FROM dbo.PBXDATA

SELECT CAST(WHEN SALES_REP = '114'
THEN 'Paul Clark'
ELSE 'NULL'
END as NVARCHAR) FROM dbo.PBXDATA

SELECT CAST(WHEN SALES_REP = '110'
THEN 'Aaron Townsley'
ELSE 'NULL'
END as NVARCHAR) FROM dbo.PBXDATA

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to perform a `UPDATE` operation rather `SELECT`. Again, you are actually trying to use `CASE` expression and your current syntax `CAST(WHEN SALES_REP = '101' ...` is wrong. You can try like below:

```
UPDATE dbo.PBXDATA SET SALES_REP = CASE WHEN SALES_REP = '101' THEN 'Ryan Kosterow'
WHEN SALES_REP = '115' THEN 'Robert Messing' 
WHEN SALES_REP = '114' THEN 'Paul Clark'
WHEN SALES_REP = '110' THEN 'Aaron Townsley'
ELSE 'NULL' END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the special `inserted` table to perform your updates. This table will be available in the trigger and will contain the row being updated. This could be the code:

```
update inserted 
set SALES_REP = 'Ryan Kosterow'
where SALES_REP = '101'

update inserted 
set SALES_REP = 'Robert Messing'
where SALES_REP = '115'

update inserted 
set SALES_REP = 'Paul Clerk'
where SALES_REP = '114'

update inserted 
set SALES_REP = 'Aaron Townsley'
where SALES_REP = '110'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad design. You really should have a SALES_REP_NAMES table which you could JOIN to the PBXDATA table when you need to have a query that outputs names. It would look like

```
SALES_REP_ID    NAME
------------    ----------------
110             Aaron Townsley
etc...
```

Than you could do something like:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  PBXDATA P
  JOIN SALES_REP_NAMES N
    ON P.SALES_REP = N.SALES_REP_ID
```

However IF you really WANT to do it via a TRIGGER it should look like the following.
Note that it avoids recursive nesting BY checking IF the TRIGGER needs to do an UPDATE.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.PBXDATA_trgIUD_sales_rep ON dbo.PBXDATA
  AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
  BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF UPDATE(SALES_REP) 
      UPDATE
        p
      SET
        p.SALES_REP = CASE WHEN SALES_REP = '101' THEN 'Ryan Kosterow'
                         WHEN SALES_REP = '115' THEN 'Robert Messing'
                         WHEN SALES_REP = '114' THEN 'Paul Clark'
                         WHEN SALES_REP = '110' THEN 'Aaron Townsley'
                    END
      FROM
        INSERTED I
        JOIN PBXDATA P
          ON I.SALES_REP = P.SALES_REP
      WHERE
        I.SALES_REP IN ( '101', '115', '114', '110' )

  END 
GO
```

Comment: Thank you for this. :) I did create a table for the sales reps as you suggested.

Comment: OP did not ask any database design question. Also in the trigger there is no need to do a join with the `PBXDATA` table; using only the `inserted` table is enough.

Comment: @srh I note that the OP disagrees with you. When you see a bad design you should point it out. Also, think carefully about your answer. Updating INSERTED is an exercise in futility. If you try you will get a message like the following:Msg 286, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ThisTable_INSERT, Line 15
The logical tables INSERTED and DELETED cannot be updated.

Comment: I agree on principle that you should point out bad designs and help out. But what I have  seen on this forum is that if you try to help out then some  people give you negative remarks for deviating from the question. So I thought this is a principle here. Agree about the update of `inserted` table and thanks for pointing out my mistake. I try to upvote your answer but this forum is not allowing me to do that unless you edit your answer. Strange.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys. I am grateful for all of your input. Last time I did T-SQL was when MSSQL Server 2005 was new. Thanks again.